# Django EOL in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls, eol

When i start my django server and type some url django always give me an EOL error:

```
SyntaxError at /accounting/payments/
    EOL while scanning string literal (urls.py, line 22)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounting/payments/
    Django Version: 1.4
    Exception Type: SyntaxError
    Exception Value:    
    EOL while scanning string literal (urls.py, line 22)
    Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
    Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Python Path:    
    ['/Users/Tone/Documents/Proyectos/macrogest/MacroTelecom',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_debug_toolbar-0.8.5-py2.7.egg',
     '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg',
     '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13-py2.7.egg',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
     '/Users/Tone/Documents/django/django',
     '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
     '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
     '/Users/Tone/Documents/Django']
```

And this is my **urls.py** code:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
#from django.contrib import admin
#admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Site control
    url(r'^$', 'macrotelecom.base.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^company/', include('macrotelecom.company.urls')),
    url(r'^people/', include('macrotelecom.people.urls')),
    url(r'^lines/', include('macrotelecom.lines.urls')),
    url(r'^accounting/', include('macrotelecom.accounting.urls')),
    url(r'^sales/', include('macrotelecom.sales.urls')),
    url(r'^shop/', include('macrotelecom.shop.urls')),
    url(r'^news/', include('macrotelecom.news.urls')),
    url(r'^map/', 'macrotelecom.base.views.webmap', name='map'),
    url(r'^error/$', 'macrotelecom.base.views.error', name='error'),

    # Internal
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/static/img/favicon.ico'}),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),

    # User control
    (r'^not_authorized/$', 'base.views.not_authorized'),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    (r'^password_change/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'),
    (r'^password_change/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'),
    (r'^password_reset/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset'),
    (r'^password_reset/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
    (r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    (r'^reset/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),

)
```

Line 22 correspond with the favicon url, i thought that could be the scape character or something like that (i put an # for comment) but didn't work, always says EOL error, what could it be?

Comment: I think the error is for line 22 of macrotelecom.accounting.urls maybe you can show that code

Comment: It is saying you have a syntax error in the urls py. It's probably quickest to find the cause if you just remove rows until it starts working (so you find which row causes the problem). Maybe some there are some non ascii characters in there messing it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That file (at least the part you posted) does not have any syntax errors. Sometimes errors can appear to come from a different files.

Check the files you've recently edited by just running the interpreter on them, `python myapp/views.py` or so. If you get NameError or ImportError, or it just runs fine, then there are no syntax errors in `myapp/views.py`, so try another file.

Comment: Yes, the error was in another file, as Cesar says, was in macrotelecom.accounting.urls, it had a break line between the last url expression and close ')', it's good know this for the future, thanks!